# Parse (iOS): User cannot be deleted unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, ios8

I'm experimenting this error only when I'm using saveEventually (iOS 8), and the Object I'm modifying **is not PFUser**:

```
var myObj = PFObject(className: "MyClass") 

myObj["val"] = 100

myObj.saveEventually()
```

<- Crash with the error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'User cannot be deleted unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107182f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109510bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107182e6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   AAA                              0x0000000105a7a85c -[PFUser(Private) checkDeleteParams] + 71
    4   AAA                              0x0000000105a3b6e9 -[PFObject(Private) _constructDeleteCommand:sessionToken:] + 81
    5   AAA                              0x0000000105a45c5c -[PFPinningEventuallyQueue _commandWithIdentifier:error:] + 147
    6   AAA                              0x0000000105a71b7b -[PFEventuallyQueue _runCommandsWithRetriesCount:] + 951
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109cb57f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109cac09a _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 852
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109ca46d2 _dispatch_source_invoke + 412
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109c9d9ae _dispatch_queue_drain + 1045
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109c9d432 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 235
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109c9ffc1 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 685
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109ca15d9 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010a039637 _pthread_wqthread + 729
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010a03740d start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The same if I'm using:

```
myObj.saveEventually{(success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

The error is not nil neither has something, **saveEventually** is just crashing.

But if I use just saveInBackgroundWithBlock or save() is working just fine...

any ideas?

I'm completely sure was working yesterday, I'm using saveEventually for almost everything in my project, but the error doesnt make sense for me, because I'm not mofifying a PFUser. Using the last SDK.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you maybe refering to the _User table in one of your columns in the table?

Comment: No @ChristianWoerz , no references at all. And as I said, if I use just save or saveInBackground is working fine, so it's a different problem :-( any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK...the solution was quite simple:

In the simulator: Reset Content & Settings
In XCode: Product -> Clean && Build
Close Xcode

rm -rf ~/library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

Open XCode

Definitely the error looked like a bug or something like that, but probably some Cache or ...whatever... was around somewhere.

Hope this helps

Cheers